Is there a way to have separate template function overloads for pointers and arrays?
First off, I would like to draw special emphasis to the C++20 tag, as I believe this problem is much easier to solve using concepts and the requires statement.
Second, when I say array here, I mean int a[3], I already have a working overload that handles the "normal" std containers, including array<int, 3> b (another for map-like containers, and another for queue-like containers).
I have a large function with a large number of overloads to handle different types using the new concepts and requires keyword to have each overload handle as many types as possible.
I cannot find a way to properly distinguish between arrays and pointers.  I would like a way that never misclassifies pointers as arrays, but if some arrays are classified as pointers, it's not the end of the world (notably, if an array has only one element, it doesn't matter at all which it is classified as).
This answer is close, but it doesn't work for this general case where I do not know what the array is of/pointer is to.
Right now I am using this for arrays:
template<typename T> requires(requires(T& a){1[a];}
                                 && !requires(T& a){a.begin();}
                                 && !is_convertible_v<T, string>
                                 )
         string function(const T& v);

and this for pointers:
template<typename T> requires(is_pointer_v<T>
                                && !requires(T& a){1[a];}
                                && !is_convertible_v<T, string>
                                )
        string function(T v);

This works classes at least pointers to strings as pointers, but everything else I tried was classified as an array.
I would think <type_traits>'s is_array_v<T> would work here; If I add it to my requirements for array and replace !requires(T& a){1[a];} with !is_array_v<T> in my requirements for pointers then pointers work as intended, but I get an ambiguous overload error for arrays because it implicitly casts it to a pointer.  I was under the impression that implicit casts didn't work in template instantiation.

An array decays into a pointer only in certain contexts, such as when passed in a parameter by value, so pass it around by reference instead. is_array_v should work just fine, and is_pointer_v should be false for an array, not ambiguous.  Please show the actual code you attempted, and show the actual error message(s) you are getting.

nvm it because I wasn't passing the pointer as a const reference.

And the code snips in there were the declarations and the error was "error: call of overloaded ‘function(std::string [5])’ is ambiguous" when I got an error.

Why not just declare the one function parameter signature as T*?

@Remy Lebeau
you think with all the messing with my tiniest grammar mistakes you did you would have seen that glaring inconsistency in my code

Not sure if this helps: But SFINE and std::size() should help differentiate arrays from pointers.

It is not all that hard if you use std::array and std::vector for your arrays instead of "C" style arrays.

Since in the array version of your snippet you're passing by reference, you can just change the parameter to const T (&ref)[N] as shown below.
template<typename T, std::size_t N> void func(const T(&ref)[N])
{
    std::cout << "array\n";
}

//for pointers only
template<typename T> void func(T) requires(std::is_pointer_v<T>)
{
    std::cout << "pointer\n";
}
int main()
{
    int arr[3]{};
    func(arr);     //calls array version

    int *ptr{};
    func(ptr);     //calls pointer version
}

Working demo

func(const T(&)[N]) will not get -Wunused-parameter

@ÖöTiib Usually, the posted code here on SO is specifically for MRE purpose. In real code they might be using the parameter ref so won't get that unused warning. But yes, if they don't use that parameter, then they can omit naming it as in func(const T(&)[N]). Though this isn't related to the original post's problem ofcourse.

Yes not related to original problem just my obsession about warnings. Use  func(T val) for better MRE and symmetry.

Could use [[maybe_unused]] on the parameter, or in the body (void)ref; to suppress the warning.  (I, also, have an obsession about warnings.)
